# Derivation of the weak Laplacian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am currently reading a textbook on spectral element methods, and the following equation is shown:

$$\int_\Omega{v\nabla^2udV=\int_{\partial\Omega}}v\nabla u\cdot\boldsymbol{n}dS-(\nabla v,\nabla u)$$

Where the last term, the weak Laplacian, is defined as:
$$(\nabla v, \nabla u) = (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}) + (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_2}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2})$$

The authors say they arrive at the first equation through the divergence theorem, but I do not understand how it applies in this case. Specifically, I do not understand how the theorem is applied when the integrand includes a second variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule, we have
$$
\nabla \cdot ( v\nabla u) = v \cdot (\Delta u) + \nabla u \cdot \nabla v.
$$
Then the divergence theorem implies
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot ( v\nabla u) = \int_{\partial \Omega} n \cdot (v\nabla u)
= \int_{\partial \Omega}  v (n \cdot\nabla u)
$$

Comment: I'm not clear on how you were able to move the gradient operator from $v \nabla^2 u$ to $\nabla (v \nabla u)$. Could you elaborate?